# ERR in npm install -g cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, npm-install

I try to install Cordova on my system but got these errors:

What can I do to solve this?

```
C:\Users\madt>npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\madt\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! file C:\Users\madt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\isarray\1.0.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\madt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\isarray\1.0.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\madt\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\madt>
```

Never had such a problem before.

Comment: "Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm has a local cache for modules which you have installed, so maybe something stuck with modules. Try:

```
npm cache clean
```

It will delete data out of the cache folder.

Comment: Tkanks a lot! That helped!